# Overwrite image on sd card android

Tags: android

I saved an image successfully on my sd card on button click. when i saved another picture my  application crashed. I have t overwrite the previous image as i want the image name to stays the same. how can i do this.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
    byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("byte array:"+image);

    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
    String fileName = "myfile.jpg";
    File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);

    while (output.exists()){
        fileName = "myfile.jpg";
        output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);

    }


        while (output.exists()){
            fileName = "myfile.jpg";
            output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);

        }


        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);


        OutputStream imageFileOS;
        try {
            imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);

            //bitmap image here
            imageFileOS.write(image);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: nothing. just set same name for all the images..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is

```
while (output.exists()){
        fileName = "myfile.jpg";
        output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);

    }
```

this will loop your code for unfinite.

Use instead

```
if (output.exists()){
output.delete(); //DELETE existing file
        fileName = "myfile.jpg";
        output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);

    }
```